# verilog, how to have a correct assignment

Tags: verilog

Please help me with this error here? I just want to write a simple fsm.
Thank you!!!

all assignment of the output such as

```
        y_a = 1'b0;
        y_b = 1'b0;
        y_c = 1'b0;
```

they appears to have the same error as following:

```
*E,WANOTL 
A net is not a legal lvalue in this context [9.3.1(IEEE)].
------
A net cannot be used as an lvalue in behavioral assignments.
Use continuous assignments when the net is an lvalue.
```

Comment: which program is producing that error? also, I think the error message describes precisely what the problem is.

Comment: Cadance Simulation on Linux

Answer (score 4):

I presume you doing that in an `always` block. However you've declared `y_a`/`y_b`/`y_c` as a `wire` (I can tell as the error says it's a net type).

To assign to a wire, you'll need to use the `assign` statement (continuous assignment).

To use the signals in an `always` block, you'll need to change them to a `reg` type.